# DataBind Repeater to List<Student> Fails to Update Data - PostBack

Tags: asp.net, list, data-binding, postback, repeater

I am trying to create a very simple ASP.NET page that allows a user to enter student data. When the form is submitted, the List of student objects is updated and the Repeater (which is databound to the list) reflects the new data. The user should be able to keep adding new students.

Mine fails to perform. I have no idea why. I have tried changing the postback and databinding methods many times.

```
   /*
     * Student class representing a real-life student.
     */
    public class Student
    {

        /* Override default constructor */
        public Student(string first, string last, string studentid, string program, string option)
        {
            FName = first;
            LName = last;
            STID = studentid;
            Program = program;
            Option = option;
        }

        /* Property for the student's first name */
        public string FName
        {
            set; get;
        }

        /* Property for the student's last name */
        public string LName 
        {
            set; get;         
        }

        /* Property for the student ID */
        public string STID
        {
            set; get;
        }

        /* Property for the program of study */
        public string Program
        {
            set; get;
        }

        /* Property for the option within the program of study */
        public string Option
        {
            set; get;
        }

    }

    /* Class for the web form UI */
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        /* List of students to be displayed in the repeater control */
        private List<Student> myStudents;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            myStudents = new List<Student>();



            /* Check postback value when the page loads - this is the first time */
            if (IsPostBack == false)
            {
                /* Bind the Collection to the Repeater control */
                Label1.Text = "" + myStudents.Count;
                Repeater1.DataSource = myStudents;
                Repeater1.DataBind();
            }


        }

        /* 
         * Submit button clicked to submit the form.
         */
        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            /* The forum has passed all of the validation rules for this case and we can add a new student to the list */
             if(Page.IsValid) {

                /*if its valid then create a new student object to put into the list of students
                  get the data from POST*/
                 myStudents.Add(new Student(FNameTextBox.Text, LNameTextBox.Text, SIDTextBox.Text, POSDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text, POListBox.SelectedItem.Text));

                 Label1.Text = "" + myStudents.Count;


              }

        }
    }
```

Here is the code for the Repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
  <HeaderTemplate>
         <table border="1">
            <tr>
               <td><b>First Name</b></td>
               <td><b>Last Name</b></td>
               <td><b>Student ID</b></td>
               <td><b>Program</b></td>
               <td><b>Option</b></td>
            </tr>
      </HeaderTemplate>

      <ItemTemplate>
         <tr>
            <td> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FName")%> </td>
            <td> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LName") %> </td>
            <td> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "STID")%> </td>
            <td> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Program") %> </td>
            <td> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Option") %> </td>
         </tr>
      </ItemTemplate>

      <AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <tr bgcolor="#e8e8e8">
          <td> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FName")%> </td>
            <td> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LName") %> </td>
            <td> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "STID")%> </td>
            <td> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Program") %> </td>
            <td> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Option") %> </td>
        </tr>
       </AlternatingItemTemplate>

      <SeparatorTemplate>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="5"><hr /></td>
        </tr>
      </SeparatorTemplate>

      <FooterTemplate>
         </table>
      </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have refactored your code, now it should work

```
/* Class for the web form UI */
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    /* List of students to be displayed in the repeater control */
    private List<Student> myStudents = new List<Student>();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){

        /* Check postback value when the page loads - this is the first time */
        if (IsPostBack == false){
          this.bindRepeater();
        }
    }

 private void bindRepeater(){
  /* Bind the Collection to the Repeater control */
            Repeater1.DataSource = myStudents;
            Repeater1.DataBind();
            Label1.Text = "" + myStudents.Count;
            }

    /* 
     * Submit button clicked to submit the form.
     */
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        /* The forum has passed all of the validation rules for this case and we can add a new student to the list */
         if(Page.IsValid) {

            /*if its valid then create a new student object to put into the list of students
              get the data from POST*/
             myStudents.Add(new Student(FNameTextBox.Text, LNameTextBox.Text, SIDTextBox.Text, POSDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text, POListBox.SelectedItem.Text));
             this.bindRepeater();


          }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I used the re-factored code and now it will display the student data I entered. However, it seems to override each time i try to enter a new student into the List! Maybe there is some setting I did not enable properly?

Comment: Is it because we are instantiating a new List each time the page is loaded and the previous list is lost?

Comment: I tried to instantiate the List at different points in time (in the page data and in the postBack but it still all fails).... Oh I am so confused...

Comment: I'm so confused about where to instantiate the List now because each time I push the submit button the Page_Load function is called! Is there an initialization function?

Comment: It might help to understand the page lifecycle a bit better.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx might shed some more light on this topic.

Comment: @user1261710 I have updated the source code again, I Initialized the student class after the ui class declaration, now it should work.

Comment: It doesn't seem to make a difference if I instantiate the List OnPreLoad or OnLoad etc. I think the DataBinding is overwriting the data previously in the list! But if I don't do it after the addition then the list has no data at all...

Comment: I initialized the List in the instance data area and it still overrides each time... I'm sure it's a problem with the data biding now.

Answer (score 2):

The DataBind is done before you add a new Student to your DataSource.

Add

```
Repeater1.DataBind();
```

In your Click event.

Comment: Bind the repeater after you update myStudents. You don't have to do it on every click. Only when you make changes to the data.

Comment: I tried to do that but it seems to override the data each time. I am not sure what's going on. Maybe there is some VS setting I did not enable properly.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why we cannot retain the values. We need to make use of sessions. A session needs to be declared before we do any databinding.